# Question owner can't write in chat created from comments - system picked wrong "Michel Keijzers"?

Tags: bug, security

See [Oscilloscope scrolling](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/474452/oscilloscope-scrolling?noredirect=1#comment1202372_474452)

I (as moderator) created a chat from the comments on the question; now the OP of the question claims that he can't write in the chat. I looked at the chatroom properties, and all of the permissions look correct to me — the OP even has explicit write permission.

Taking a closer look, the OP of the question is https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/140343/michel-keijzers, but the system gave access to https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/65345/michel-keijzers.

OK, following links even further, it seems that the OP's chat profile link does indeed end up at the same chat user page, so that isn't the problem (just extremely confusing!). Why can't he write in the room?

---

OK, never mind! The OP says that it's working now. Was anything changed, or was it just cockpit error?

Comment: You can always [blame caching](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/221414/158100) ...